# Undefined behaviour on std::prev for transform-view

Tags: c++, c++20, undefined-behavior, std-ranges

Consider the following code ([click here for godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/afbqbGbvs)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto v = std::vector<short>{1, 2};
    auto view = v | std::views::transform([] (auto i) { return static_cast<int>(i); });
    auto it = view.begin() + 1;
    auto prev_it = std::ranges::prev(it); //this one is fine
    //auto prev_it = std::prev(it); //this one dies with an infinite loop

    return *prev_it;
}
```

**Main question:** Calling `std::prev` instead of `std::ranges::prev` on the iterator makes gcc run into an infinite loop. This means there’s a compiler bug or the code calling `std::prev` invokes undefined behaviour – which one is it?

---

Some thoughts on the latter: [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) requires a [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), whereas [`std::ranges::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/prev) requires the [*concept bidirectional_iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/bidirectional_iterator). From my understanding, the only difference between these two is (taken from the description of *bidirectional_iterator*):

> Unlike the *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* requirements, the *bidirectional_iterator* concept does not require dereference to return an lvalue.

If this indeed means that calling `std::prev` invokes undefined behaviour: Do basically all non-ranges algorithms invoke undefined behaviour when called with iterators of the new kind, as [*LegacyForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) and [*forward_iterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) share the same difference? Could the constraints for the old algorithms not be relaxed to the new iterator-kind, to avoid exactly this, as that would be still backwards-compatible?

Comment: Note that input iterators don't have that difference.

Comment: [std::advance](https://godbolt.org/z/6G7cj99PP) fails in the same way

Comment: visual studio fails with "negative advance of non-bidirectional iterator"

Comment: I'm guessing this is the cause of the infinite loop: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h#L147

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ah, it falls back on an input iterator, which this iterator is.  And the implementation assumes it only goes forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This means there’s a compiler bug or the code calling `std::prev` invokes undefined behaviour – which one is it?

The latter, although libstdc++ should be able to detect this failure and diagnose it better [as it does if you ask it to](https://godbolt.org/z/qxGnb4Yer).

The issue here is that given:

```cpp
auto view = v | std::views::transform([] (auto i) { return static_cast<int>(i); });
```

`view`'s iterators are C++20 random access iterators, but because their reference type is a prvalue `int`, they can only be C++17 input iterators. That's just the way the pre-C++20 iterator model worked: forward iterator required a true reference.

`std::ranges::prev` uses the C++20 iterator categories, `std::prev` uses the C++17 (or really C++98) iterator categories. And `std::prev` requires `BidirectionalIterator`. It's unspecified to what extent the library needs to try to validate that the iterator is indeed bidirectional, but `prev(it, n)` is specified as `advance(it, -n); return it;` and `advance(it, n)` for non-bidirectional iterators will just loop until it hits `n`... which for negative `n` will clearly never happen.

That said, if you're using Ranges, you should be using `std::ranges::meow` instead of `std::meow` in all cases, because of this iterator category difference. This case is pretty dramatic since it's "works" vs "infinite loop", but note that `std::next(it, 100)` would be a loop that increments `it` 100 times while `std::ranges::next(it, 100)` would return `it + 100`, so even when they both "work" it's still a significant difference.

Comment: Not really important but I can not get std::next to be slow for this case, are you talking in general in  last paragraph or about this particular case? https://godbolt.org/z/r69zshrh4

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The optimizer helps you out in this case - you can see that on `-O1` we still have a loop: https://godbolt.org/z/x1fs4hPGf

Comment: Ah, now it is obvious, but I never assumed the optimizer will be smart enough to do this... but then again it is literally a  simple loop :) Thank you

Comment: What are C++20 iterator categories? Is there any reference in the standard or in cppreference pages?