# Emplacing to the back of a forward_list segfaults

Tags: c++, list, containers, emplace, forward-list

This must be a stupid oversight on my part, but how can I add to the back of a `std::forward_list`? I know usually the `forward_list` implementation doesn't contain an iterator to the back, but according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/end) the standard `forward_list` is required to have one (constant time), so I thought I might as well use it.

Now, the way this is supposed to work is that `emplace_after()` will look at the node before the given one and re-link its `next` pointer. This makes it clear that I need to insert after the node before `cend()`, so do `std::prev()`. But, if there's no element in the list at all, this will result in a node *before* `begin()`, which is still [perfectly covered by the implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/before_begin). The given [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/emplace_after) of `emplace_after()` does so itself. So, I thought I would be fine, but this segfaults ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3GhYYanhW)):

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <forward_list>

struct entity
{

    entity()
        :   mylist_{ std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>{}}
    {}
    
    auto add(int i) {
        // printf("start = %p, end = %p", &*mylist_.cbegin(), &*mylist_.cend());

        auto it = mylist_.emplace_after(std::prev(mylist_.cend()));

        *it = i;
    }

    auto print() {
        std::ranges::for_each(mylist_, [](int i){ printf("%d\n", i); });
    }

    std::pmr::forward_list<int> mylist_;
};

int main()
{
    entity e;

    e.add(4);

    e.print();
}
```

I checked `start` and `end` iterators with the commented-out `print` statement, and they point to the same address.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm surprised `std::prev(mylist_.cend()` even compiles given the iterators aren't bidirectional

Comment: You should track the last element of a non empty list in the class `entity`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You are of course correct that slipped my mind. Is there any way to make use of the end iterator or is it just there to provide a sentinel?

Comment: @AlanBirtles std::ranges::prev() doesn't :) should've been consistent.

Comment: @glades I'd say that `forward_list` isn't the correct container if you need to insert at the end (at least if you want to do it often).  You could of course create a similar container that provides an interator to _before end_ too for those cases.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok I settled for a bidirectinoal list now, but those back ptrs sure seem like a waste.

Comment: _"those back ptrs sure seem like a waste"_ - it depends on what you need :-) If you really don't want to use `std::list` then implementing a `forward_list` that provides a set of `before_end()` member functions shouldn't be impossible - and also a bit of fun :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::forward_list` only provides forward iterators which means you can't use `std::prev`.

[libstdc++ doesn't implement type requirements for iterators by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486663/undefined-behaviour-on-stdprev-for-transform-view) when calling `std::prev`. The implementation of `std::prev(it)` is to just call `std::advance(it, -1)`. For forward iterators `std::advance` has a debug asssertion to check that the distance is positive (but debug assertions won't normally be enabled), the implementation then does:

```
while (distance--)
{
  iterator++;
}
```

As `distance` is negative this will iterate quite a few times but actually crashes on the first increment as `mylist_.cend()++` is undefined.

MSVC does better here and rejects your code: https://godbolt.org/z/e4G3M9n44.

You could solve this by having `entity` store a reference to the last element but you'd be better off just using a container that better meets your requirements like `std::list` or even `std::vector` (due to lack of memory locality linked lists often have poor performance on modern CPUs).

Comment: Thanks excellent answer! I'm aware of the performance implications of the list, but the allocated objects can't be moved or copied, so instead of having a vector of unique_ptrs I thought it would make sense to have an std::list which I can splice and track the state of the objects in different lists. Also, this goes on an embedded system so there's no cache anyway :)